# Multiple sockets for different messages Vs parsing different messages on one socket

Tags: java, sockets, parsing, port

I am working on an application which receives different types of messages(about 4 types of messages). I wanted to know what would be better:

1. Have different ports for different message types, with the sending application sending the message on appropriate port
2. Send the messages on one port, distinguished by an id field or something, and parse them

Could someone please tell me which method would be more advantageous in terms of performance? I personally think having different ports would be better. Could someone please tell me if this is the right approach to do this?

Comment: TBH unless you have a **huge** amount of messages it's not going to matter much, at all. Go for what is easiest to code/maintain.

Comment: I am going to have a huge number of messages. In that case, which one would be better?

Comment: define "huge" (in bytes)

Comment: think of it like this: in case the actual processing power needeed for parsing those messages is less than what one core can handle it is not going to matter. If you're having one machine dedicated to process the messages then you will benefit from running them on different threads (and different ports). Otherwise, the context switch is probably going to hurt at least as much as the performance benefit of running them on different ports.

Comment: If you care about performance in a serious way, you should look at `netty`. We process tens of thousands of HTTP requests per second per commodity server with Netty. And it'll make whatever you're trying to do comparatively simple in code.

Comment: I am building an application wherein 100s of clients route their requests to a server via my application and these clients issue simple read queries on a dbms. I do want a robust system which should be able to handle tens of thousands of messages per second.

Comment: Four message types isn't confusing enough to need four different ports, unless your application protocol is so badly designed that they can't be readily distinguished. @NinoWalker I fail to see how Netty constitutes an answer to, or even a relevant comment on, this question.

Comment: `Netty` is relevant insofar the question is about protocols, networking, messaging and high throughput. All of which Netty does an exceptional job at. If a reader is unfamiliar, they should take a serious look.

Answer (score 1):

Start with one socket, cause that will be way easier to maintain (sorting out multiple network ports for applications can be a pain, especially if there are firewalls involved).

assuming you write your code with reasonable encapsulation around the socket handling, if you get to a point where you truly need multiple sockets for performance (and you have *proved* this with actual testing), then it should be fairly easy to make the change later.